# OpenVPN configuring client to use subnet topology results in "inet prefix is expected rather than 10.66.10.6/-1"

Tags: networking, openvpn, subnets

Right now whenever I connect to a (commercial) VPN server a `tun` interface spins up with an `inet` address assigned to it as well as a `peer` one (whatever that means).

```
root@mininet-vm:/etc/openvpn# ip -4 a show dev tun0
33: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    inet 10.9.10.6 peer 10.9.10.5/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I'm have two virtual interfaces that I want to have all their traffic pass through the VPN. I can get this to work by routing traffic from these interfaces to `tun0` and doing an `SNAT` to `10.9.10.6`. I have tried to assign ips like `10.9.10.7` and `10.9.10.8` to them but I only get response traffic on `tun0` when the `src` is `10.9.10.6` (hence why SNAT worked).

I was wondering it's possible to turn `tun0` into a regular subnet so that I can assign more than one clients on that subnet and do this without resorting to NATing.

I have found the topology option on openvpn man page but this option seems to be pushed by the server

```
subnet -- Use a subnet rather than a point-to-point topology by 
          configuring the tun interface with a local IP address and 
          subnet mask, similar to the topology used in --dev tap and 
          ethernet bridging mode.
```

I have tried to override it with `/usr/sbin/openvpn --topology subnet --pull-filter ignore "topology" ...` but it fails when adding the IP:

```
Fri Dec 28 01:52:47 2018 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.66.10.6/-1 broadcast 255.255.255.254
Error: an inet prefix is expected rather than "10.66.10.6/-1".
```

Is there any other way to get this to work? (unfortunately I cannot control the server this a commercial VPN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no control over the server then you can't do this.

The TUN interfaces handles *layer three* packets (as opposed to a TAP interface, which handles layer two). The server will have static rules for routing and you wont be able to change this using only client side configuration.